# Angular 16 Unit Test with Jasmine -> signInWithEmailAndPassword (from angular/fire/auth) spy not working properly

Tags: angular, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, jasmine

I have a unit test with Angular 16 and jasmine and the "signInWithEmailAndPasswordSpy" is not working properly.

It throws the following error: "Expected spy sendPasswordResetEmail to have been called with:
[ Auth({  }), 'test@test.com', 'abcde123' ]
but it was never called."

I wonder if the mock implementation of this spy is not correct. I would appreciate any input. Thanks in advance.

This is my LoginPageComponent.ts:

```
import {
  Auth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocaleService } from '../../shared/services/locale.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;

  hide: boolean = true;

  loading: boolean = false;

  serverMessage!: string;

  type = 'login';

  route = '';

  constructor(
    private afAuth: Auth,
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    public router: Router,
    private localeService: LocaleService,
    private location: Location
  ) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((_) => {
      if (!this.location.path()) {
        return;
      }

      this.route = this.location.path();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  get email() {
    return this.form.get('email');
  }

  get password() {
    return this.form.get('password');
  }

  get isLogin() {
    return this.type === 'login';
  }

  get isPasswordReset() {
    return this.type === 'reset';
  }

  changeType(reqType: any) {
    this.type = reqType;
  }

  handleServerError(err: any): string {
    switch (err.code) {
      case 'auth/missing-email':
        this.serverMessage = $localize`Error: Missing email address`;
        break;
      case 'auth/invalid-email':
        this.serverMessage = $localize`Error: Insert your email address and password`;
        break;
      case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
        this.serverMessage = $localize`Error: This email address is already in use by another account`;
        break;
      case 'auth/user-not-found':
        this.serverMessage = $localize`Error: User not found. Verify your credentials`;
        break;
      case 'auth/wrong-password':
        this.serverMessage = $localize`Error: Password and email address mismatch`;
        break;
      default:
        this.serverMessage = $localize`Error: Something went wrong`;
    }
    return this.serverMessage;
  }

  async onSubmit() {
    this.loading = true;

    const email = this.email?.value.toLowerCase();
    const password = this.password?.value;

    try {
      if (this.isLogin) {
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.afAuth, email, password);
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }
      if (this.isPasswordReset) {
        await sendPasswordResetEmail(this.afAuth, email);
        this.serverMessage = $localize`Check your email`;
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      this.serverMessage = this.handleServerError(err);
    }
  }

  changeLanguage($evt: Event, locale: string) {
    $evt.preventDefault();

    this.localeService.setLanguage(locale, this.route);
  }
}
```

and this is my HTML file:

```
<div class="bg">
  <main>
    <div class="card">
      <div *ngIf="isPasswordReset">
        <h2 i18n class="mb-5 mt-5" *ngIf="isPasswordReset">Reset Password</h2>
        <button
          i18n
          style="height: 3rem"
          class="btn btn-primary mb-4"
          (click)="changeType('login')"
        >
          Back to login
        </button>
      </div>

      <form
        class="d-flex flex-column gap-3"
        [formGroup]="form"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
      >
        <mdb-form-control *ngIf="!isPasswordReset">
          <div class="input-group border round form-control-lg">
            <input
              i18n-placeholder
              mdbInput
              mdbValidate
              formControlName="email"
              type="email"
              id="formEmail"
              class="form-control"
            />
            <label i18n mdbLabel class="form-label" for="formEmail"
              >Email</label
            >

            <mdb-error i18n class="mt-3" *ngIf="email?.invalid && email?.dirty">
              You must enter a valid email address
            </mdb-error>
          </div>
        </mdb-form-control>

        <mdb-form-control *ngIf="!isPasswordReset">
          <div class="input-group border round form-control-lg">
            <input
              i18n-placeholder
              mdbInput
              mdbValidate
              formControlName="password"
              [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
              id="formPassword"
              class="form-control"
              #pwInput
            />

            <label i18n mdbLabel class="form-label" for="formPassword"
              >Password</label
            >

            <div
              class="input-group-text border-0"
              style="cursor: pointer"
              (click)="hide = !hide"
            >
              <i
                [class]="hide ? 'fa-regular fa-eye-slash' : 'fa-solid fa-eye'"
              ></i>
            </div>

            <mdb-error
              i18n
              class="mt-3"
              *ngIf="password?.invalid && password?.dirty"
            >
              Password must be at least 6 characters long
            </mdb-error>
          </div>

          <div class="form-helper">
            <div class="form-counter">{{ pwInput.value.length }} / 6</div>
          </div>
        </mdb-form-control>

        <button
          i18n
          style="margin: auto; height: 3rem"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary"
          *ngIf="isPasswordReset"
          type="submit"
        >
          Send Reset Email
        </button>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between gap-2 mt-3 w-100">
          <button
            style="height: 3rem"
            class="btn btn-primary login-btn"
            *ngIf="isLogin"
            type="submit"
            [disabled]="form.invalid"
          >
            <span i18n *ngIf="!loading">Login</span>
            <span
              *ngIf="loading"
              class="spinner-border"
              style="width: 1.5rem; height: 1.5rem"
              role="status"
            ></span>
          </button>

          <button
            i18n
            class="btn btn-light"
            *ngIf="!isPasswordReset"
            (click)="changeType('reset')"
          >
            Forgot password?
          </button>
        </div>

        <span
          class="mt-1 mb-4"
          [class]="
            isPasswordReset ? 'text-primary fw-bold' : 'text-danger fw-bold'
          "
          >{{ serverMessage }}</span
        >
      </form>

      <div *ngIf="isLogin" class="language">
        <span i18n>Select language:</span>
        <div mdbDropdown class="dropdown">
          <i
            class="fa-solid fa-globe dropdown-toggle fs-5"
            id="dropdownMenuButton"
            aria-expanded="false"
            mdbDropdownToggle
          ></i>
          <ul
            mdbDropdownMenu
            class="dropdown-menu"
            aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink"
          >
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeLanguage($event, 'en')"
                >English</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                id="link-es"
                class="dropdown-item"
                (click)="changeLanguage($event, 'es')"
                >Español</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Finally, this is my test file for this component:

```
import {
  ComponentFixture,
  TestBed,
  fakeAsync,
  tick,
  waitForAsync,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  Auth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FormBuilder, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './login-page.component';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardPageComponent } from '../../dashboard/dashboard-page/dashboard-page.component';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { LocaleService } from '../../shared/services/locale.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

describe('LoginPageComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginPageComponent>;
  let router: Router;
  let mockAuth: jasmine.SpyObj<Auth>;
  let auth: Auth;

  const signInWithEmailAndPasswordSpy = jasmine.createSpy<
    typeof signInWithEmailAndPassword
  >('signInWithEmailAndPassword');

  const sendPasswordResetEmailSpy = jasmine.createSpy<
    typeof sendPasswordResetEmail
  >('sendPasswordResetEmail');

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    mockAuth = jasmine.createSpyObj<Auth>('Auth', ['signOut']);
    auth = new Auth(auth);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardPageComponent },
        ]),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        SharedModule,
      ],
      declarations: [LoginPageComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: Auth, useValue: mockAuth },
        {
          provide: signInWithEmailAndPassword,
          useValue: signInWithEmailAndPasswordSpy,
        },
        {
          provide: sendPasswordResetEmail,
          useValue: sendPasswordResetEmailSpy,
        },
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    location = TestBed.inject(Location);
    spyOn(location, 'path').and.returnValue('/dashboard');

    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));

    const formBuilder: FormBuilder = TestBed.inject(FormBuilder);
    component.form = formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required]],
    });

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

 it('should log in the user when valid email and password are provided and redirect user to /dashboard', fakeAsync(() => {
    const email = 'test@test.com';
    const password = 'abcde123';

    component.form.controls['email'].setValue(email);
    component.form.controls['password'].setValue(password);

    const loginButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button.login-btn'));
    loginButton.nativeElement.click();

    tick();

    expect(component.serverMessage).toBeFalsy();

    expect(signInWithEmailAndPasswordSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );

    tick();

expect(component.router.navigateByUrl).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/dashboard');
  }));
});
```